# Create a username and password in RStudio Server

Tags: server, 16.10

I installed RStudio Server and I could possibly get access to this server with `http://<server-ip>:8787`. From there, they asked me a username and a password, but I don't even know what it could be. It is possible to get a little bit more information from that [website](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started).

(See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGbfX.jpg))

Could anyone be able to tell me how could I create these two pieces of information?

Comment: RStudio Server uses the credentials of the Linux user on the server to access the   RStudio interface.

Comment: How are you sure of that. On their webpage, download RStudio Server is free. So why do we have to pay something?

Comment: No, you do not have to pay, you said you installed it yourself so I assume you have access to a server, if you have a username and password to access your profile on that server use those to log into the Rserver system.

Comment: I installed RStudio Server in using this website (https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/), but once I have had done this, I didn't know what was my username and password for that server.

Comment: The computer that you installed the server to should have a user on it whose username and password you should use at the Rstudio login page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with what we call a "server". They explain on the website (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started), that "RStudio will prompt for a username and password, and will authenticate the user by checking the server's username and password database." What does it mean according to you?

Comment: It means the same thing I said to you, the same username and password you use to log into your computer that the Rserver is installed on may be used to log into the Rstudio login page.

Comment: Yes, it's exact.

Comment: Ok no problem, It is a lot easier than most people think, I guess that is what surprised you. Have fun, it is a brilliant piece of software

Comment: Why did you say "it is a brillant piece of software"?

Comment: Another question for you : they explain we could get access RStudio from any other computer. Do I need to use the ip server of that other device?

Comment: I mean it is nicely designed and will increase your productivity in creating nice reports based on calculations. If you install this on a properly configured server from Linode or any other good VPS you can access it from almost anywhere in the world from another computer.

Comment: If you have this on a private network then see how to fix the IP number of your server and then use that IP on another computer to gain access, on the other hand if you have something to resolve names ,a  local DNS server for example, you could use a nice name for your server and connect that way. There are tons of help available for setting up a server both for Linode and internally.

Answer (score 3):

Every user in the linux system can login in the rstudio IDE, unless you limit it, for example to certain groups:

```
# /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf

auth-required-user-group=analysts,admins,rstudio-users
```

You can check more details at [RStudio user documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating-users.html#restricting-access-to-specific-users)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use your username and password to login to the ubuntu as stated by @rodrigobb, and if your Rstudio is running in a container, you can just create a user and set the password as follows:

```
useradd abc
passwd abc
```

Don't forget to [make a home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714548/3552975) for user abc:

```
mkdir /home/abc
chown -R abc /home/abc
```

Otherwise, you'll get this error prompt:

> could not connect to the r session on rstudio server unable to connect to service